# Comparing movie ratings by different critics

Tags: statistical-significance

I have a question for a problem that I am dealing with. My records are movie names, and my variables are the ratings for the movie, by three critics (Critic 1, critic2 and critic 3), at different points in time ( T1 - time before watching trailer, T2- Time after watching trailer, T3- Time after watching movie). The last three columns are the "TRUE" ratings that were given by an independent body. 
My data looks like this : 
[image]

I have a list of about 50 movies. I would like to ask certain questions like this 
(a) Within a time period ( t1,t2,t3), does the assessment of the critics vary significantly? 
(b) How far away are the critics ratings from the actual ratings ( for different time periods) ? 
(c) Which groups were similar in their assesment?

So far, to answer question a, I subtracted the rating values and did a paired one 't-test' to see if the difference is significant.

Is this the right way to approach this problem ?